# plt.imshow() of matplotlib, change size of pixels

Tags: matplotlib, imshow

I am learning to draw contour plots using matplotlib's imshow() function. The following code gets me a contour plot with pixels much too large. Not what I was expecting. Does someone know how to fine-tune the parameters of the function to get a much finer resolution?

I tried to experiment with the aspect keyword parameter with the value auto, but that didn't solve the problem...

The example is from the book "Python Data Science Handbook" from Jake VanderPlas, first printed edition, p. 241.

```
plt.imshow(Z, extent=[0, 5, 0, 5], origin='lower', cmap='RdGy')
plt.colorbar()
plt.axis(aspect='image');
```

[image]

Comment: `imshow` just shows an image. How did you create `Z`?

Comment: Did you look at https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.04-density-and-contour-plots.html ?

Comment: You can use `x = np.linspace(0, 5, 500)` to get 500 points in the x-direction instead of only 50. You could do the same for y.

Comment: Hi @JohanC: Thanks for your comment, I just replicated the code of Jake VanderPlas (defined the function z = f(x, y) as it is specified under the link you have given). But my image does not look the same in respect of resolution.

Comment: The dimensions of X and Y define the dimensions of Z. Just increase them as much as needed.

Comment: Yeah, you are right: when I extend the arrays, then it works. Many thanks @JohanC! I used x = np.linspace(0, 5, 50) and y = np.linspace(0,5, 40). For a higher resolution I have to use x = np.linspace(0, 5, 500) and y = np.linspace(0, 5, 400).